# Patent application intellectual property rights

Tags: invalidation, us7305928

In reference to the patent: [US7305928](https://www.google.com/patents/US7305928)

I filed for this work on 6/10/2005.  (I can provide the complete package filed.)  The examiner did not like my format, so I paid an attorney to refile, on 4/5/07.  In the meantime Bradley filed the above patent using my work, on Oct 12, 2005.  When I contacted Brunswick, they said Bradley was fired.

What rights do I have?

Comment: please provide your patent application number.

Answer (score 1):

Its unclear to us whether both subject matter was same and you have priority over inventive subject matter, however if you feel you have the priority and your disclosure was novelty destroying then you can initiate re-examination over granted patent. Keep in mind that the at that time US was first to invent therefore if your reduction to practice was in fact earlier you might get some relief.

As you filed application in US therefore it might be screened by US examiner I doubt that he missed your application but just in case please cross check the entire search strategy of the US patent and if your patent application is not listed then you can raise some queries in front of USPTO.